# Qt. Почему в release можно из другого потока изменять GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, gui

У меня был класс, в который я передавал указатели на виджеты, а он делал там вычисления в бесконечном цикле и изменял виджеты. В дебаге вылетало практически сразу, в течение 1-2 секунд, но вот в релизе у меня программа могла работать несколько часов подряд, а после этого зависал сам интерфейс. Никаких сегфолтов или "программа не отвечает", просто интерфейс реагировал на каждый клик в течение секунд 10, окно программы и вывод с помощью `qDebug()` работали как обычно. Если нужен код - могу показать, но не вижу смысла, тем более его достаточно много

Comment: "зависал интерфейс" не означает, что можно изменять GUI из другого потока

Comment: @BeardedBeaver я передавал указатель в другой поток, там делал setText, всё работало в течение нескольких часов

Comment: То, что оно у вас по какой-то счастливой случайности не сдохло, никак не говорит о том, что так можно делать. Налаживайте общение между потоками с помощью сигналов.

Comment: В коде есть неопределённое поведение, которое, по традиции, компиляторы пытаются превратить в падение в Debug режиме. В Release версии никаких дополнительных проверок нет, и НП может до поры до времени оставаться незамеченным. Если код падает в любом режиме, значит в нём есть проблема.

Comment: В этой версии зависает на 10 секунд, в следующей начнет жесткий диск форматировать. После того как вы нарушаете правила использования некоторого инструмента, он вам больше ничего не должен.

Comment: >>Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread. As noted earlier, QCoreApplication::exec() must also be called from that thread.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Нет, я конечно не говорю, что так можно делать, мне как раз интересно, почему оно сразу же не падало

Comment: Заголовок вашего вопроса содержит слово "можно". Почему сразу не падало - вам выше про неопределенное поведение написали.